# Object property key is different within req.body than client-side (Express)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm a bit of a noob working on my first CRUD application (dream journal) using Node, Express, and MongoDB/Mongoose.

I'm creating a simple object based on a few user form inputs and then submitting a post request to the server, which in turn calls Mongoose.save().

The object I'm creating on the client side, however, is slightly different than the one that is being received by the server, and I'm at a complete loss as to why.

First I'm getting some values from a form and putting them in an object:

```
    // within button click event handler

    var dreamText  = $('#dream-text').val().trim();
    var dreamTags  = ["tag 1", "tag 2", "tag 3"]; // for debugging
    var dreamLucid = $('#dream-lucid').val() == 'Yes' ? true : false;
    var dreamDate  = $('#dream-date').val();

    var dream = {
        userID: 'test',
        text: dreamText,
        tags: dreamTags,
        isLucid: dreamLucid,
        dateCreated: dreamDate
    };
```

Here a console.log of dream shows everything as it should be:

```
Object {userID: "test", text: "sample text", tags: Array[3], isLucid: false, dateCreated: "2016-08-08"}
```

From there I'm submitting a POST request with the dream object:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/new',
        data: dream,
        success: function(data){
            console.log('dream saved');
        }
    });
```

Now on the server side, with Express and Mongoose, I'm attempting to save the object to a DB:

```
router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var newDream = Dream(req.body).save(function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            throw error;
        }
    });
});
```

All the properties except tags are saving correctly, and a console.log of `req.body` yields:

```
{ userID: 'test',
  text: 'sample text',
  'tags[]': [ 'tag 1', 'tag 2', 'tag 3' ],
  isLucid: 'false',
  dateCreated: '2016-08-08' }
```

Any idea why the `tags` property on the client side is becoming `'tags[ ]'` when it gets passed through the POST request?

I've tried both `tags: Array` and `tags: [String]` in my Mongoose Model, but the problem seems to be occurring before I ever call `Mongoose.save.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `$.ajax()` encodes a POST operation as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which does different things with arrays.  You probably just want to send JSON so you can receive JSON on the server.

You can cause that to happen by manually turning your data into JSON and setting the content type appropriately:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/new',
    data: JSON.stringify(dream),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log('dream saved');
    }
});
```

Then, you may also have to parse the JSON on the server side of things, either manually for this request or with some middleware like `bodyParser.json()`.

Comment: It's working now, thank you! I found that I also had to use `bodyParser.json()` on the server side.

Comment: @E.Walsh - Yes, that makes sense.  Something on the server side has to parse the JSON.  Since it looks like you're new here, if this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of this answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure.